# Wifi not working Elementary OS Loki 0.4

Tags: release-loki, wifi, drivers

I install Loki 0.4 on a MacBook White Dual core 2,4 Ghz. The wifi is there but try to connect and time run out (server not found). I think it may be wifi drivers. Please help.

Answer (score -1):

Encontré la solución para mi caso corrigiendo el controlador para Ralink. RT3290 y ahora me funciona el Wi-Fi; acá les dejo el enlace:
http://onthim.blogspot.com.ar/2015/06/install-ralink-rt3290-wi-fi-driver-on.html

Answer (score -2):

Instalé Loki 0.4 en arranque dual con Windows 10, el wifi a veces funciona en Loki y otras veces me dice desactivado he probado todo lo que encuentro en Internet y me funciona pero al apagar y volver a prender ya no vuelve a funcionar el wifi, en otras distribuciones no he tenido ese problema solo con Loki ¿Alguna ayuda definitiva?